# How to wrap vanilla javascript functions to reactjs without major modifications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, migration, binary-tree, prototype

This is part of my migration job from vanilla javascript to reactjs

```
export const WTree = () => {


    function Tree() {
        this.root = null;
    }


    Tree.prototype.traverse = function(val) {
        this.root.visit(1);
        console.log(this);
        // this.root.visit(this.root);
    }

    Tree.prototype.sorted = function(val) {
        var tree = new Tree();
        this.root.sorted(tree);
        tree.traverse()


    }


    Tree.prototype.addValue = function(val) {

        var n = new Node(val);
        if (this.root == null) {
            this.root = n;   
            // this.root.x = width / 2;
            // this.root.y = 16;
        }
        else {
        this.root.addNode(n);
        }
    }

    Tree.prototype.remove = function(val) {
        // debugger;
        var n = this.search(val)
        if (n != null) {
            if (this.root == n) {

                if (this.root.right != null) {
                    this.root = this.root.right;
                } else if (this.root.left != null) {
                    this.root = this.root.left;
                }

            }
            n.remove();

        }

    }

    Tree.prototype.search = function (val) {
        var found = this.root.search(val);
        if (found == null) {
            console.log(val + ' not found');
        } else {
            console.log(val + ' found');
        }
        return found;
    }



    return Tree
}
```

I just wrapped legacy code within

```
export const WTree = () => { 
}
```

Now I have to use normally in ReactJs

```
import { WTree } from 'components/binarytree/tree'

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    let tree = WTree.Tree
  }
}
```

But I have to apply similar logic on 100s of components, so I don't want to modify or touch too much on legacy codes.
Now I am losing readability from WTree.Tree

I am thinking to use simple approach as below to gain more readability

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    let tree = Tree

  }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Not sure what you mean by "migrating from vanillajs to reactjs" - it looks like you're just trying to use a data structure inside a `React.js` component, and there's no need to migrate anything, you can use any valid `JavaScript` code inside `React.js` components without issues or migrating to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is just to use a data structure inside a `React.js` component - there's need for "migration" or changing anything. `React.js` is just a UI library so unless you're moving from one UI library to another, you don't have to migrate anything.

Your `BinaryTree`-related code is not legacy code - it's just `JavaScript`. You don't have to wrap anything inside arrow functions and then export it - this is not something that's `React` specific or it requires.

Just do:

```js
function Tree () {
  this.root = null;
}
Tree.prototype.treverse = function(val) { ... }
// ...

export default Tree;
```

Then in your `React` component, just do the following:

```js
import Tree from './components/binarytree/tree';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.tree = new Tree()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // this is an example of a lifecycle method and how
    // you could use your tree data structure
    this.tree.addValue(...)
  }

  render() {
    // do whatever you need to do here
  }
}
```

**Note:** You most likely don't want to do `let tree = new Tree()` inside the `render` method, so move it to the `constructor` and use it however you need it in one of the lifecycle methods and/or event handlers.

---

Alternatively, if you do want to use the `import { Tree } from '...'` syntax, you could change your `tree.js` slighly by doing the following:

```js
export function Tree () {
  this.root = null;
}
Tree.prototype.treverse = function(val) { ... }
// ...
```

Then, you can do:

```js
import { Tree } from './components/binarytree/tree';
// ...
```

Hope this helps.